# Pig hadoop returning 0's in division

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to divide H by AB for each line. H / AB in the below line way below divies but produces an out of all ZEROS. I am really confused.

```
sum_of_scores = FOREACH final_group GENERATE group AS id,
            SUM(s.AB) AS AB,
            SUM(s.H) AS H;


final_final = FOREACH sum_of_scores GENERATE $0 AS month_state, $1 AS AB, $2 AS H;

dump final_final
```

[image]

```
out_put = FOREACH final_final GENERATE month_state, (H / AB) AS score; 

dump out_put
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though the expression `(H / AB)` is using integer division, so the arguments should first make use of the [cast operators](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/basic.html#cast) to convert to `float`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon the answer above, each column should explicitly be cast to a float:

```
out_put = FOREACH final_final GENERATE month_state, (FLOAT)((FLOAT)H/(FLOAT)AB) AS score;
```